# Cannot access environment variables on port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, port80

I'm working on a rails application and in my dev environment I'm forced to use port 80. Running on any other port that would require me to go to `localhost:xxxx` isn't gonna work.

I run the application with `rvmsudo rails s -p 80` after stopping apache.

Everything works fine except that I can't seem to access my environment variables here. Running on regular ports (3000, 4000, etc) works fine and I can access them when I can use those ports, but when I can't and **have to** use 80 I'm stuck.

Is there something I should be running when I start up the rails server? Or some alternate way of accessing the environment variables that would work everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` and `rvmsudo` start a subshell that doesn't contain environment variables. `rvmsudo` only forwards on certain environment variables [see more](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/qt/Rvm-And-Sudo.htm).

In your scenario, are you saying that this *doesn't* work:

```
rvmsudo rails s -p 80
```

And that this *does* work?

```
rvmsudo rails s -p 3000
```

Also, are you trying to access environment variables other than these: `$PATH`, `$GEM_HOME`, `$GEM_PATH` and `$BUNDLE_PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I have a few apis I'm working with and their keys are stored in environment variables. When I do regular old `rails s` they work fine. Haven't tested with `rvmsudo rails s -p 3000` on my second machine, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

The environment variables I'm trying to access are all stored in the .profile file

Comment: `sudo` and `rvmsudo` start a subshell that doesn't contain environment variables. `rvmsudo` is just a special kind of `sudo` that preserves environment variables necessary for ruby to run.

Comment: Isn't there a way to pass my own environment variables to rvmsudo, then?

Comment: That looks like it might help. Thanks!